# Retrieve value from other site, in PHP?

Tags: php

Retrieving a value inside of a span id?

```
<span id="playerCount">157,767 people currently online</span>
```

How would I go about getting the value inside that ID? I thought of preg_match() but is that even safe?

Comment: bad idea, that's mean your page render time will be `original page render time + the external site render time + network latency`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use php's DOM methods. The following code assumes you have allow_url_fopen enabled:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$span = $domd->getElementById("playerCount");
$span_contents = $span->textContent;
```

Comment: Does this depend on the website being well formed tho?

Comment: @Jacob: it does not need to be valid, if that's what you mean. I've seen quite broken code interpreted well by DOMDocument, but also met edge cases where parsing failed. Those codes were a terrible mess however, not even my browser could sensibly display them.

Comment: thanks good to know. I wasn't aware of the `libxml_use_internal_errors()` function when I tried, maybe that's what stopped me going further.

Comment: Brilliant idea! I never knew DOM methods existed.

Answer (score 0):

With Regex this is possible and very easy. If it were something more advanced I'd instantly recommend using a tool created for parsing HTML (see DOMDocument)

```
<?php
// content containing: '<span id="playerCount">157,767 people currently online</span>';
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
preg_match('/<span id="playerCount">([0-9,]+) people currently online<\/span>/', $content, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```